# Context Menu Item tap event disabled when isZoomEnabled is false.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, contextmenu

I tried to implement toolkit:contextMenu for user defined control for wp8 app. but as i set the property IsZoomEnabled to false, the tap event of menu items is not invoked. 
Please help regarding the matter. 
The following is the code implemented.

---

```
          <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:ContextMenu VerticalOffset="100.0" x:Name="menu" Background="{StaticResource PhoneSemitransparentBrush}" IsZoomEnabled="False">
                   <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="mnuItem1" Header="Item1"
                                  Tap="Item1_Tap" Foreground="White" FontSize="30"/>
                <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="mnuItem2" Header="Item2"
                                   Tap="Item2_Tap" Foreground="White"/>
                <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="mnuItem3" Header="Item3"
                                  Tap="Item3_Tap" Foreground="White"/>
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```